# Getting error Element not interactable on trying to send Page Down keys to div

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll Telegram using selenium in python. In the attached screenshot I have shared I have selected 'Members' as the element to send Keys.PAGE_DOWN as it is stick all the time to top and is static while scrolling so it should be visible all the time and can be the perfect element to send Keys.PAGE_DOWN to.
But on sending page_down I get error 'Element not Interactable'.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I have attached the script and screenshot.

I am using python 3.10 and selenium latest version.

```
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='RightColumn']/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`
```

[image]

I have tried all the answers currently available on the internet and they don't work here. This looks like some complex issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think Selenium is throwing the right error message as this div is not an interactable element and you are trying to send keystrokes into the element.

Another approach for scrolling is using Javascript commands.

1. Find an element locator you need to scroll to.
2. (Ex: if you need to scroll to the bottom find the element at the bottom)
3. Use the below code to scroll

```py
# Find the element in the page to scroll to
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//element/at/bottom/of/the/page")

# Fire javascript command to scroll in to view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: Will this work the same or do I need to implement the Javascript one?

def scroll_to_element(element):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

Comment: Move to element will not perform any scrolling if that is what you are asking. It will invoke the mouse hover action to the element which will not achieve what you are looking for. I suggest you use the javascript action as it is simulating the real page scroll through javascript